# How to run a .exe file with command prompt?

Tags: c, windows, execution

I am making an online judge. This my school project.

I am taking a `.c` file from the user. I am able to compile the `.c` file with command prompt. But I don't know how to run this file. I need to run this file, take input from a text file and save output in a text file. The compilation code was:

```
    gcc main.c -o HelloWorld
```

Comment: seem you are using linux,so `$./HelloWorld`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to run this file, take input from a text file and save output
>   in a text file.

Assuming you're on Linux, this should work:

```
./HelloWorld < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW i am using windows. its working except i dont have to use ./ at the start. :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're on Linux? If yes, run it with:

```
./HelloWorld
```

The `./` is needed so that the shell knows to look for the executable file in the current directory. (Executables are not looked for automatically in the current directory due to security reasons.)

If on Windows, just type its name:

```
HelloWorld
```

Appending `.exe` to the filename is optional.

Redirecting standard input works like this:

`HelloWorld < inputfile`

Standard output is redirected with `>` instead:

`HelloWorld > outputfile`

You can combine both:

`HelloWorld < inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: yes, i am using windows, how would i make sure that the .exe program in taking the input from a specific text file, and writing the output in a specific file

Comment: @eddard.stark `HelloWorld < inputfile > outputfile`

Answer (score 2):

Just type in the full path. For example, if you compiled the file in `%homedrive%` with the name `dummy.exe`, type `%homedrive%/dummy.exe`.

Also, if you're already in `%homedrive%`, you can just type `dummy.exe`.

**Edit**: Assuming you're on Windows.

Comment: yes, i am using windows, how would i make sure that the .exe program in taking the input from a specific text file, and writing the output in a specific file

Answer (score 2):

When you type HelloWorld in Linux terminal, your system will be searching this program in place, where PATH variable indicates. Most likely it is /bin. You can check your PATH by typing:

```
echo $PATH
```

So, you must precise, that HelloWorld is in concrete dirctory or change $PATH variable.

```
./HelloWorld
```

Dot indicates current directory

Answer (score 1):

You can install [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/)

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run
```

or else try the option `./HelloWorld`

Comment: Why would he install that ?

Comment: @mux:- Thats an option which I recommended else OP can try simply by doing ./HelloWorld as suggested by other(also updated in my answer)!!

Comment: but he's already compiling with GCC, why use a different compiler ? and that line looks like it belongs to a script.

Comment: Thats just a recommendation which I thought. If you want I can delete that!!

Comment: no it's your answer, you're free to say what you want, just trying to understand the reason :)

Comment: @mux:- The reason was that as  this is a compiler that will compile and run directly from source code.